# What steps do I take after downloading the iso file onto my USB and what will happen to my device upon installation of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, usb, updates, bios, syslinux

I was initially going to just upgrade my Ubuntu version through the update manager, but after my computer restarted during the upgrade (yes, I followed every troubleshoot guide that I could find), I have decided to abandon my current installation and just start fresh.

I downloaded the iso file and mounted it to my USB. Everything is ready, but now I am realizing I have NO idea what to do next nor do I know what will happen to my pre-existing installation.

- Does the new install unconditionally wipe my hard drive?
- Can I get it to wipe my hard drive?
- Will it override my old version?
- Will it get bogged down because of my old version?
- How do I boot from disc? I've use <kbd>F12</kbd> on the startup, but it never gave me an option to boot from disc.
- How do I enter the BIOS and change the boot sequence?

I have no idea what to do now. Could someone assist me?

EDIT:

I tried again. I went into the BIOS, selected to move the USB to the top, and now my computer won't really start. I'm not on a laptop. I told it to do a full boot, so when I select to go to the boot menu, it counts up to 640MB, then it says to select IPL device. So I select USB, then it says:

> SYSLINUX 3.63 Debian-2008-07-15 EVIOS copyright (c) 1994-2008 H. Peter Anvin Boot:

Comment: Just boot from the USB and follow the graphical installation procedure. Same as windows. How more simple can it get? :)

Comment: @Nick how do I boot from disc? In previous attempts, I've used F-12 on the startup, but it never gave me an option to boot from disc. I'll try again and comment.

Comment: You could enter the BIOS and change the boot sequence , in your case set the USB drive as 1st device to boot .

Comment: While very tech-savvy, when it comes to Ubuntu, I've always been to lazy to learn everything. How do I enter the BIOS and change the boot sequence? @Nick

Comment: At the startup screen hit F1 or F2 (to me its F1) then go to Advanced BIOS Features -> Change Boot Sequence - > move the removable device(USB) first, hit F10 to save (or exit and select Yes to the popup dialog) and you are ready to boot.(Make sure you restore the boot sequence when install the new OS))

Comment: On my PC if I press f12 on the "dell" bios screen I can choose the boot device from a list

Comment: I need to ask, is your current OS is Ubuntu or Windows?You said that you want to start fresh so, did you take a backup?

Comment: @Nick okay, so I fully retried. I went into the bios, selected to move usb to the top, and now my computer won't really start. I'm not on a laptop. I told it to do a full boot, so when I select to go to the boot menu, it counts up to 640 mb, and then it says to select IPL devise. So I select USB... then it says "SYSLINUX 3.63 Debian-2008-07-15 EVIOS copyright (c) 1994-2008 H. Peter Anvin
Boot:

Comment: Your are using an old version of syslinux. try a new one or follow this workaround: http://forums.partedmagic.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=522&start=0#p1985

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that when you install, you will have the option to rplace or upgrade your current installation. You can also choose "something else" & partition manually. If you choose anything beside upgrade or install along side, yes, it WILL wipe your hard drive. So if thats what you want, its thaat simple. IF you want to keep your files, run an upgrade OR install it along side your current install.